# can LOAD DATA INFILE use a giving path instead of the default mysql data path?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use LOAD DATA INFILE to upload xls/CSVfile content into mysql database.

the file in which I want to upload is located on a different path that the databases. I don't want to put the xls/CSV file in my same path as my data so I put them into a different path. but it seems that MySQL ignore the path I am providing It always searching for a file located in the data bases directory.

here is my code

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\uploads\new_campaign_request.xls'
INTO TABLE new_db.new_campaign
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

How can I get MySQL to search for the file

Answer (score 3):

```
       LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\\uploads\\new_campaign_request.xls'

       INTO TABLE new_db.new_campaign(column_name)

       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

User double back slash for load file path and define column name in which data should be loaded